# What differences between `type cd` and `which cd` commands in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, command

What differences between two below commands in CentOS7?

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

and

```
$ which  cd
cd is a shell builtin
cd is /usr/bin/cd
cd is /bin/cd
```

The `cd` is a **shell builtin** command, but why `which` command show another path for cd ? 
Is the cd command both **internal** command and **external** command ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`which` shows the full path of (shell) commands.
its output is different based on different systems.
`type` display information about command type on Linux.
  (see man page for more info)
we have 4 command types:
Built-in Shell Commands
Shell Functions
Command Alias
excutable Programs

for example:

```
# type ll  
ll is aliased to `ls -l --color=auto'  
# type cd  
cd is a shell builtin
# type sudo  
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: In my `/bin` and `/usr/bin/ directories`, I have `cd` command. So, i want to know, what differences between cd builtin command and these two?

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Linux `CentOS7`

Comment: check this out. https://askubuntu.com/questions/532788/why-wouldnt-the-which-command-work-for-cd-i-cant-find-the-executable-for

Comment: @BlackCrystal - What is the use case for the `type` command? When is it used and for what purpose?